# Is there a way to watch LINQ queries as they happen?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have recently been looking into LINQ and wanted to know more about it and was searching for a simple method of visualizing my queries to get a bit more detail on what is going on during the query.

Does anyone know of any tools that are openly available to accomplish something like this?

Thanks,

Josh

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might want to take at this article on [Visual LINQ](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/02/20/visual-linq-watch-query-expressions-as-they-happen.aspx) at Jon Skeet's blog. Visual LINQ is a tool that will allow you to visually watch your LINQ query in action.

You can directly download the files for it [here](http://pobox.com/%7Eskeet/csharp/blogfiles/visuallinq/VisualLinq.zip).

Hope this helps.

**Edit:** Scott Gu's blog also has an article on the [LINQ to SQL Debug Visualizer](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/31/linq-to-sql-debug-visualizer.aspx), which might help you out.

Comment: Wow - I didn't know something like that existed! Thanks Rionmonster, this should be what I need!

Comment: And if you wanna do just a little debugging output, you can use DataContext.Log, or DataContext.GetCommand(query).CommandText

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what sort of LINQ you're talking about. If you're referring to LINQ-to-Objects, then WYSIWYG; with the exception of some methods that get optimized for certain standard framework libraries (e.g. the `Count()` extension method on `IEnumerable` is smart enough to call the `Count` property if the target enumerable implements `ICollection`), there's no real optimization that's done on a case-by-case basis.

For something like LINQ-to-SQL, you'll have to use a database-specific monitoring tool, like SQL Server Profiler for MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use SQL Profiler in SQL Management Studio (not available in express edition).  You can see how SQL server handles the Linq queries.

Comment: While profiler isn't included with Express editions, you *can* run traces on an Express-powered database. This means that an existing install of Profiler can run on an Express database, and the standard T-SQL commands will work as well.

Comment: @Adam: Thanks for the info. I will have to remember that on my future project. Do happen to have any good links to direct me to? Is that MS SQL profiler or another comps software?

Comment: Here's a good place to start looking: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188662.aspx I haven't used any GUI tools other than SQL Server Profiler, but I'd be really surprised if they didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Profiler is probably your best bet. You can watch as queries are executed and have a running log of everything that has happened. It's quite configurable, you can set it to capture only the events you're interested in.

Try this video tutorial: http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Using_SQL_Server_Profiler

Answer (score 0):

A great tool for Linq to SQL queries that I've used many times is the [Linq to SQL Profiler](http://l2sprof.com/). Not only does it show your queries, but it also helps you understand how they can be optimized to avoid pitfalls such as N+1.